# Create record from interface with return type as property type from original interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an interface like

```js
inteface A {
  a: number
}
```

I want to create type of an object with keys as keys of A and values as function which return type of the key

example

```js
const obj = {
  a: () => 4
}
```

What should be the type of `obj` here which should be a generic which takes `A` interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a mapped type for this:

```js
type Functionify<T> = { [K in keyof T]: () => T[K] }
```

It loops over all keys (properties) in the type `T` and maps them to a function returning the original type `T[K]`.

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsGoGYgDwAqAfFALxQDeUA2gNJSoJQDWEI62UBAugFxQAKAJRkSBOtygBfALAAoeY2AQATtgCGSaAEFK8qFHX8EcALYAjVfNkK5STAGdgUdOYBW-eMjSYc+bSTkFPqG-MKiUAAs1kA)